# Can I call SetCurrentDirectory from an NPAPI plugin code in a multithreaded environment?

Tags: windows, multithreading, gstreamer, npapi

I need to load gstreamer plugins from an NPAPI plugin, without adding the plugin path to the
PATH environment variables, and without using GStreamer's plugins registry.

The only method I found to work is:
Calling the Windows API SetCurrentDirectory, 
Loading each plugin using gst_plugin_load_file,
Calling SetCurrentDirectory
to set back the original directory (normally the browser's executable folder).

Is there any problem to use this method in a multi-threaded setting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you should avoid this. The current directory is per process, not per thread - you'd get random errors if anything in any other thread depended on the current directory.

`gst_plugin_load_file` looks like it should support absolute paths - that would be the right way.

Comment: yeah; it might actually work in development, but if anyone else was foolish enough to do the same thing and both plugins got loaded at the same time, both would probably break in fairly unpredictable ways.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the replies. 
I think I found a better way: 
Instead of SetCurrentDirectory, I call SetDllDirectory.
After loading the gstreamer plugins, I call SetDllDirectory(NULL), 
in order to restore the default dll search order.